# Delphi 2007 - Error handling, not hitting the 'except' section

Tags: delphi, exception

I wrote a primitively simple code where I tried to debug the situation that arose in my project. I'm trying to get into an exception when creating a new window, but I don't get there, why is this? Tell me what's wrong? or what to read for understanding.

**So I get to the 'except' section!**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Local: TForm2;
begin
  try
    //Local := TForm2.Create(nil);
    //Local.Show;

    raise Exception.Create('not implement');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin

    end;
  end;
end;
```

**I need to handle this situation. I don't get into the 'except' section like that**

**Module Form1.pas**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Local: TForm2;
begin
  try
    Local := TForm2.Create(nil);
    Local.Show;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin

    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Module Form2.pas**

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  raise Exception.Create('not implement');
end;
```

Comment: First create the object, then enter the try..except section.

Comment: The project was provided to me for support, unfortunately when there is a lot of that. Otherwise, the problem cannot be solved? It is necessary in all places where such code is found to rewrite the creation of the object after the try ... except section ?

Comment: Do you currently get a messagebox with the exception message?

Comment: Make sure you have the debuuger option `Stop on language exceptions` unchecked, otherwise the debugger will intercept the exception before the app has a chance to handle it.

Comment: Blurry Sterk Yes. And I want to catch it and not lift it. And even after the exception, the Form2 window opens, which should not be.

Comment: And its not the usual "Stop on language exceptions"?

Comment: MartynA, I checked this out and tried all sorts of different options to turn exceptions on and off. (there is enough information on this topic on the Internet, but did not get the desired result)

Comment: Blurry Sterk, I tried "Stop on language exceptions", did not help" !

Comment: You shouldn't be catching exceptions at all. This is one of the great mistakes people make. Don't handle the exceptions. Let the top level exception handler deal with them.

Comment: David Heffernan, I believe that you are right, but I already have such a code, and I already need to do something with it, at least not open the window that appears after the exception. (now Form2 window opens)
P.S. The project was transferred to me for support. It already contains similar lines of code.

Comment: I am curious... What are the exceptions caused in the `OnCreate` that you need to catch? Shouldn't you be preventing "errors" and catch the others inside `OnCreate` itself?

Comment: Blurry Sterk, At the moment, I have met only classic Exception.Create("..."). I have not seen any unique (written by the previous developer) exceptions in the code.

Comment: If you inherited a project then I assume that you are going to do some extra work to get this working so you can do it right from the start in anyway

Comment: Blurry Sterk, yes, I'm trying to figure out if this situation can be corrected or if everything needs to be rewritten. If you write to me that "it cannot be fixed", then I will accept the information as is and will rewrite the code. 

Сomplaints from customers are usually like this: An error occurred and then a window was opened (which should not have opened).

Comment: Nobody here knows what your code actually looks like so you will have to make that decision. You will have to do your best to try and glue all advice from here together to form some sort of coherent solution. I gave you an answer based on your specific question but that might not be the best solution for your complete project. You will have to decide

Comment: Blurry Sterk, I will rewrite, thank.

Comment: "at least not open the window that appears after the exception. (now Form2 window opens)" That only happens because your code handles exceptions!!

Comment: David Heffernan, if my code had handled the exception, then the `Local.Show()` code would not have been executed.

Answer (score 2):

You will see that `DoCreate` that is called from `TCustomForm.Create` has `OnCreate` inside a try and its exception passes the exception to `TApplication.HandleException` which will pass it to `TApplication.OnException` if one is assigned.

If think if you override your form's `HandleCreateException` you can return a result of `False` which will allow the exception to passthrough

Comment: Blurry Sterk, сan you give an example please?